# Как правильно написать xpath

Tags: xpath

Есть страница на которой надо спарсить ссылки
Код страницы имеет след вид:

```
<div class="company-list-item"><a href="УРЛ" class="com-logo content-a">
```

мой вариант не работает и не могу понять почему
'//a[@class="company-list-item"]'

Answer (score 0):

Всё логично: у вас в пути в качестве имени тега указано `a` а в качестве класса `company-list-item`. Либо замените `a` на `div`, либо `company-list-item` на `com-logo content-a`

Comment: спасибо, чтоб не плодить темы <div data-url="урл" id="29152"></div> как вот такое в xpath записать?

Comment: @Елена На сколько помню, как то так `//div[@id="29152"]`. Давненько не уже не работал с XPath

Comment: id там меняться будет постоянно и там много мусорного id на странице, по ходу надо из data-url как брать, а вот как незнаю

Comment: `по ходу надо из data-url как брать` - ну я же не ванга. вы сформулируйте задачу от начала и до конца, и тогда я подумаю что можно ссделать. вытягивать из вас условия задачи мне не интересно

Comment: согласна))) есть <div data-url="урл" id="29152"></div>  надо собрать из этого дива урл, а потом я все урл запишу в список